# Pass the same parameters to node for multiple scripts in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

In my `package.json`, I have several scripts that call `node` with the same parameters over and over. To simplify that invocation, I've created a `package.json` variable, and am invoking the scripts like this:

```json
{
  "nodeParams": "--experimental-specifier-resolution=node --harmony -r source-map-support/register",
  "scripts": {
    "dothis": "node $npm_package_nodeParams myscript.js",
    "dothat": "node $npm_package_nodeParams another-script.js",
    ...
  }
}
```

This is quite common for calling compiled TypeScript code, and worked fine in NPM v6.

However, it no longer works in NPM v7 due to [a breaking change](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major):

> [RFC 21](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md) Environment no longer includes npm_package_* fields

What is [the currently recommended solution](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/305), or some alternative?

Comment: Why not have a script e.g. `"node": "node --experimental-..."`, then `"dothis": "npm run node -- myscript.js"`?

Comment: Or move nodeParams under the `"config"` key, which is apparently [coming back](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/pull/183).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just need to use `npm_package_config_*`

From the link you provide (https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md)

> Each key in the config object will be included, but npm will not override values with a `<pkgname>:<keyname>` config value if one exists.

e.g.

```
{
  "config" : { "nodeParams": "--experimental-specifier-resolution=node --harmony -r source-map-support/register" },
  "scripts": {
    "dothis": "node $npm_package_config_nodeParams myscript.js",
    "dothat": "node $npm_package_config_nodeParams another-script.js",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't revert legitimate edits - that's *not* (quite) the URL the OP provided, it's the one I linked in my previous comment, and without backticks <pkgname> and <keyname> disappear from your answer.